# Comparison parameter "-as" in Powershell

Tags: powershell, operators

Just stumbled on this Powershell code:

```
if (!($email -as [Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
    Write-Output "ERROR: invalid email: $($email)"
    exit -1
}
```

I searched the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3) on Powershell comparison operators, but I could not find what "-as" means.
My guess it compares if the string is a valid object of *Net.Mail.MailAddress* but I am not sure what it does exactly.

Comment: `-as` is a [Type Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2). It's used to safe type coercion, it attempts to coerce the string as a `Net.Mail.MailAddress` in your example.

Comment: Yes it is a type conversion operator. Returns the value on the left cast to the .net type on the right. If PS can't convert it returns $Null